# static polymorphism and template Containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, rtti, static-polymorphism

I'm trying to use the static polymorphism and template to create a container that can hold more the one type, from what I know about template it can't be done, but I'm hoping that I'm wrong and there is a way. 
I have the following classes:

```
template<class Derived>
class base
{
public:
    base(string);
    void clean()
    {
        cout << "I'm cleannig \n";
    }
    void process()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setup();
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->run();
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->cleanup();
    }
    string name;
};

template<class Derived>
base<Derived>::base(string y):name(y)
{
}


class derived : public  base<derived> 
{
    friend class base<derived>;
    void setup() {cout << "derived setup \n"; }
    void run() { cout << "derived run \n"; }
    void cleanup() { cout << "derived cleanup \n"; }

};


class derived1 : public base<derived1> 
{
    friend class base<derived1>;
    void setup() {cout << "derived1 setup \n"; }
    void run() { cout << "derived1 run \n"; }
    void cleanup() { cout << "derived1 cleanup \n"; }
};
```

and I wont to create a container that can hold them, I tried this code -

```
template <class T>
class Y{
 public:
 std::vector<base<T>> m_vec;   

};


template <typename T>
class D:public Y<T>
{
    public:
    friend class Y<T>;
    void print()
    {
        for(auto& e: Y<T>::m_vec)
        {
            e.process();
        }
    } 
};


int main()
{ 
    base<derived>* b =  new base<derived>;
    base<derived1>* c =  new base<derived1>;

    D<derived> y;
    y.m_vec.push_back(b);
    y.m_vec.push_back(c);
    y.print();
}
```

but its not working
i tryed to do this:

```
 y.m_vec.push_back(static_cast<base<derived>>(c));
```

and I'm getting this error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector, std::allocator > >::push_back(base*&)’
>            y.m_vec.push_back(b);

Comment: base<derived> and base<derived1> are different, unrelated types.

Comment: You can make a container of some type-erasure or std:: variant over your types.

Comment: fwiw containers can hold objects of different type, look for "type erasure", `std::any` or simply `std::vector<baseClass*>`

Comment: The _static type_ of all things in the container must be the same. This means static polymorphism is not compatible with it. However, the elements can have different _dynamic_ types (which, of course, is run-time polymorphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some testing and digging the answer is that there isn't a way to do it. **but** you can use std::any like @formerlyknownas_463035818 suggested
declare the std::vector as :

```
std::vector<std::any> m_vec;
```

Instead of

```
std::vector<base<T>> m_vec;
```

and use the boost demangle function to get the type -

```
std::string name(boost::core::demangle(e.type().name()));
```

and then use some kind of factory functio to any_cast to the type you need

```
 if(!name.compare("base<derived1>*") )
 {
     try {
             auto* r = any_cast<base<derived1>*>(e);
             r->process();
         }
         catch(const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
             std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
         }
  }
  else
  {
     try {
         auto *r = any_cast<base<derived> *>(e);
         r->process();
     }
     catch(const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
         std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
     }
   }
```

or instead of using the demangle name and use string compare you can use the type() function of the class any and compare is to the typeid like this:

```
    if(e.type()==typeid(base<derived1>*))
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have no information about the actual type at the time of calling the `process()` function, this is impossible.

---

Starting with C++17 you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/variant) to store the type information. You can make `process` a static function that gets as argument an instance of a class derived from `base`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::string name): name_(std::move(name)) {}

    template <typename T>
    static void process(T& self) {
        std::cout << "process " << self.name_ << '\n';
        self.run();
    }

protected:
    std::string name_;
};

struct A: Base {
    using Base::Base;
    void run() { std::cout << "run A " << name_ << '\n'; }
};

struct B: Base {
    using Base::Base;
    void run() { std::cout << "run B " << name_ << '\n'; }
};
```

Then you can create a `std::vector` of `std::variant` of `A` and `B`. Call `process()` through a generic lambda in a visit statement.

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::variant<A, B>> array{A{"Cat"}, B{"Dog"}};
    for (auto& element: array) {
        std::visit([](auto& a_or_b) {
            Base::process(a_or_b);
        }, element);
    }
}
```

```
process Cat
run A Cat
process Dog
run B Dog
```

---

With C++23 that can be simplified a bit more.

```
import std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(std::string name): name_(std::move(name)) {}

    void process(this std::derived_from<Base> auto& self) {
        std::print("process {}\n", self.name_);
        self.run();
    }

protected:
    std::string name_;
};

struct A: Base {
    using Base::Base;
    void run() { std::print("run A {}\n", name_); }
};

struct B: Base {
    using Base::Base;
    void run() { std::print("run B {}\n", name_); }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::variant<A, B>> array{A{"Cat"}, B{"Dog"}};
    for (auto& element: array) {
        std::visit([](auto& a_or_b) {
            a_or_b.process();
        }, element);
    }
}
```

Four points are different:

1. The includes have been replaced by the C++23 [module](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) `import std`.
2. `std::cout` has been replaced by [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print).
3. `process` is now a normal non-static member function in the new C++23 notation with [explicit `this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter). It is still a template, but constrained by a [C++20 concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).
4. The call now uses the normal member function call syntax `a_or_b.process();`.